# orderBy:notarray Expected array but received: Object

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter my results by it's position.

But as soon a orderby it breaks the page since the result is not an array. How can I change this? I'm stuck with this.

I do this like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in content | orderBy : 'pos'" class="animated zoomIn">
```

And the controller:

```
firebase.database().ref("v3/standalonelist/" + catId.toLowerCase()).on('value', function(snapshot) {

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.content = snapshot.val();
      console.log($scope.content);

    })

  });
```

$scope.content returns this object:

```
{
  "Bar One" : {
  "bgurl" : "https://domain.com/aa/bars/list/bar.jpg",
  "name" : "Bar One",
  "subtitle" : "Cheers",
  "pos", 2

},
"Bar Two" : {
  "bgurl" : "https://domain.com/aa/bars/list/bar.jpg",
  "name" : "Bar Two",
  "subtitle" : "Cheers",
  "pos", 1
 }

}
```

And i get this error:

> [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: [THE OBJECT ABOVE]

Comment: Error is true, this is an object which is wrap another objects. Your content should be like that : $scope.content = [
 {
  "bgurl" : "https://domain.com/aa/bars/list/bar.jpg",
  "name" : "Bar One",
  "subtitle" : "Cheers",
  "pos", 2

},
{
  "bgurl" : "https://domain.com/aa/bars/list/bar.jpg",
  "name" : "Bar Two",
  "subtitle" : "Cheers",
  "pos", 1
 }

]

Answer (score 1):

**1)** **Customized  filter (AngularJS)** **for orderBy Object property..**

Example JSON:

```
{ 
   "123": {"name": "Test B", "position": "2"},
   "456": {"name": "Test A", "position": "1"}
}
```

Try this link...

[orderBy filter for Object](http://jsfiddle.net/4tkj8/1/)

**2) Another one way to acheive orderBy filter for Object properties.**

- Add an array of your data objects:

`$scope.dataArray = Object.keys($scope.data)
   .map(function(key) {
    return $scope.data[key];
  });`

In view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataArray | orderBy:'order.allListPosition'">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BXgYPTElSM3sjvLg30CL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You model is object not an array, so you should use `(key, value) in experssion` synatx.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please make an example?

Comment: For ordering properties inside the object you can't use `orderBy` filter procided by angular because it orders collection. To solve your issue you should either change your data structure to provide collection or make your custom filter ot order properties inside an object.